# if else is only logging last command given without comparing-javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object, if-statement, boolean

Could someone take a look at my function and tell me why my "if else" statement is not working properly? I need the function to compare the values of "inStock" and "weeklyAverage" within each object and provide me with a true/false answer. I am a beginner so please forgive my novice question. How do I fix this to where it gives me an answer per object?

```
 let inventory = [
      { candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 },
      { candy: "Sour Patch Kids", inStock: 90, weeklyAverage: 100 },
      { candy: "Milk Duds", inStock: 300, weeklyAverage: 170 },
      { candy: "Now and Laters", inStock: 150, weeklyAverage: 40 }
    ];


 function shouldWeOrderThisCandy(inventory, candy)
{
   for (let i=0; i< inventory.length; i++)
  {
    if ((inventory[i].inStock) < (inventory[i].weeklyAverage))
    {
      answer= true;
    }
    else
    {
      answer= false;  
    }
    return answer
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of 1st run of iteration, i.e., for the first element of the inventory, e.g. `{ candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 }` you are running conditioning part

```js
if ((inventory[i].inStock) < (inventory[i].weeklyAverage))
    {
      answer= true;
    }
    else
    {
      answer= false;  
    }
```

then directly return `answer` that is set to either `true` or `false`. A function returns the value that is written right after `return` whenever it sees `return`. You are returning a value (`answer`) at the end of first iteration, so the function returns the logical result obtaining by comparison executed on the first object in array. Execution would be read as noted below:

```
{ candy: "Twizzlers", inStock: 180, weeklyAverage: 200 }
inventory[0].inStock = 180
inventory[0].weeklyAverage = 200

inventory[0].inStock < inventory[0].weeklyAverage
        180          <           200

answer = true
return true
```

Comment: Thank you, how should I go about fixing this? do I need to create multiple for-loops?

Comment: You can use `map` method of Array. See example code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/fat9v0z5/). When you run that code snippet, you will have an array ( `stockStatus` ) with boolean values. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#) for more information about JavaScript Array methods.